# Salvar texto multilinha em campo Blob no SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Gostaria de uma ajuda nessa questão de salvar um `EditText` multilinha em um campo blob no banco SQLite, pois quando eu adiciono no `ContentValue values.put(CriaBanco.OBS, pedido.getObservacao());`   no banco ele salva os textos no **Blob Editor** com ponto final sinalizando as quebras de linha, já no **Text Editor** do blob, só salva a 1ª letra da 1ª linha.

**Segue a imagem do campo blob na IDE SQLite Expert:**

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: se e texto pq vc nao usa text no lugar de blob ? e pra ficar melhor pros colegas te ajudar acho que se possivel posta o query que vc est usando